# Magento 2: Validation message in XML

Tags: layout, magento2.3, xml, validation

I want to edit the validation message on some input fields. I see that input fields are defined in the xml file (checkout_index_index.xml). Is there a way to override validation message in this xml?

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
  </item>
</item>
```

Comment: You want to edit validation message of the same validator but for different field? For example, the validator is `required-entry`, but with `telephone`, it's "telephone required", with `zipcode`, it's "zipcode required"? Am I correct?

Comment: yes instead of saying "This field is required" i want to do "first name field is required"